# Dynamic titles lag or do not show - Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

So, I have an issue with my dynamic title on my report

My issue:

My dynamic titles sometimes with uncheck filters looks like this "MTTR OOS -" when it should look like this "MTTR OOS" or with filters checked it won't show it in the title.

Below is the code I use

```
Sub Chart Title = 
VAR ReportName = " MTTR OOS  "
VAR SelectedOffer =  IF( ISFILTERED( 'MTTR'[co_cr]), "- " & SELECTEDVALUE('MTTR'[co_cr]),"")
VAR SelectedType =   IF( ISFILTERED( 'MTTR'[cust_type_code]), " " & SELECTEDVALUE('MTTR'[cust_type_code]),"")
RETURN
 IF( 
     SelectedOffer=" " && SelectedType=" ",
     "Latest Report",
     ReportName & " " & SelectedOffer & " " & SelectedType
     )
```

From the above code my dynamic title works the issue I am running into is sometimes depending on how I use my filters the "-" would still show up after unselecting all filters and sometimes my filters do not show up in the dynamic title. I do have 17 pages with dynamic titles on each and 1 graph on each with only 2 filters for the whole report. Is there a way to fix the "lag" or a fix on my Dax function to have the dynamic titles to run smoother and show what is actually selected?

Answer (score 0):

In the calculation, `SelectedOffer` and 'SelectedType' is either a value or an empty string, i.e.:

```
VAR SelectedOffer =  IF( ISFILTERED( 'MTTR'[co_cr]), "- " & SELECTEDVALUE('MTTR'[co_cr]),"")
```

The return statement checks if `SelectedOffer` and 'SelectedType' are a single space, so it would seem that "Latest Report" would never be returned:

```
IF(SelectedOffer=" " && SelectedType=" ",
```

But that would not explain why you are seeing "MTTR OOS -".  Seems like this must mean an empty value is selected.  You could try using HASONEFILTER, which checks to see that at least one value exists: https://dax.guide/hasonefilter/

Regarding performance, it's possible that this is caused by other intensive queries.  Check out this video to see about optimizing each report page:

https://www.sqlbi.com/tv/analyzing-a-slow-report-query-in-dax-studio/